# jQuery not first or last failing despite index() being perfect

Tags: jquery

This is a section of code that is part of a touch scroll function. To simplify I have moved non relevant code:

```
$(".banner .slides").swipe({
  var sl_active = $(this).find(".slide.active");
  if(sl_active.not(":first, :last")){ alert("test")}
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="slides">
    <div class="slide" style="background:red;">ONE</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background:yellow;">TWO</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background:green;">THREE</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background:blue;">FOUR</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background:orange;">FIVE</div>
  </div>
```

The alert triggers on every slide regardless of whether it is the first or last. Alerting the index reveals that slide 0 is the first and slide 4 the forth. I have checked that the active class is not inadvertently applied to all slides and it is not, nor would the rest of the code work if it was. Cannot see the problem.

PS. `.not(":first").not(":last")` have also been tested.

Comment: And what is `swipe` ? Why do you variables and `if` statements inside something that looks like an object literal? Are you missing a function here?

Comment: Also, it's always not first or not last, it can't be both, unless there's just one element, and `not()` returns a jQuery collection, which is always truthy

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't explain it.

Comment: @adeneo swipe is a function. For purpose of simplicity I have not included its source code.

Comment: Again, the code you posted seems like invalid syntax, you can't have variables inside object literals. Did you mean `.swipe(function() { ... })`

Comment: Here's some more code that should put that one to bed. .swipe( {
    swiping:function(e, dir, locationl, tim, effect) {.  // Get it

Comment: Now you're getting somewhere, at least it's valid code that will run, not just a syntax error.

Comment: Now try to replace `not` with `is` and see what happens

Comment: Try to alert `sl_active.index()` instead.

Comment: @adeneo this I attempted and well to no avail.

Comment: @skobaljic: This triggers correctly as stated in the question. In the end I have had to calculate the length (ie. number of elements) and use index() as for reasons unknown, nothing else is triggering.